# How to use sticky position relative to root level element?

Tags: html, css, sticky

I want to use sticky position for an element that is inside for example header element, but stay on top of the page when I scroll down.
Now I just can stick it to the top of my header, not the whole page.
For example something like the header of this page you are.
I can use header selector in the css file instead of nav, but in this case the image also sticks to the top that I don't want.

```css
nav {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
  border-right: thin solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
  border-left: thin solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  float: right;
}

a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header style="height: 500px;">
    <img src="https://html.com/wp-content/uploads/html-hpg-sublime.png" alt="image" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <article style="height: 1000px">
    some article here...
  </article>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
nav {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
  border-right: thin solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
  border-left: thin solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  float: right;
}

a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <img src="https://html.com/wp-content/uploads/html-hpg-sublime.png" alt="image" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  <div>
  <h3>Where does it come from?
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</h3>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes it works perfectly. What if I want to keep my header element? is there any way to do that?

Comment: @SMhdAsadi can you little more?

Comment: As I said in my question title, I want to know that is it possible to use sticky position relative to root element?

Comment: @SMhdAsadi yeah sticky will work with root having relative position.